# Python/Django : Frontend/Backend Question

Tags: frontend

I am new to Python/Django world. I am looking for some help to create a webpage similar to below link:

http://www.mceinsurance.com/resources/uk-motorcycle-accident-hotspots

It seems there's animation and it is using following jargon.

```
-webkit-animation
::-webkit-scrollbar
@-webkit-keyframes rotate
```

Need help in understanding frontend. If I have to design similar website what frontend should I choose given the fact backend will be python/django framework.

Spinet of the code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)}    
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar { height: 12px; width: 12px; background: #ccc; }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background: #999; -webkit-border-radius: 
 1ex; }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover { background: #858383;}
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active { background: #bd0e0e;}
```

Comment: This question is a) completely subjective and b) totally unrelated to Python or Django.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. What do you suggest if I have to design webpage similar to above link?

Comment: I'm afraid that front-end web development is a vast field, with a huge - and ever-increasing - number of tools and technologies that can be used. This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, but all I can suggest for now is to first learn the basics of CSS and Javascript, then take a look at whatever tools take your fancy. Of which, as I said, there are very many.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Robin. Appreciate it.